# ¿Como imitar el comportamiento de <marquee> con una animación css?

Tags: html, css, animación

Tengo un animación muy simple que trata de imitar la función de la etiqueta `<marquee>`, en esta muestro los colaboradores del mes de la empresa hasta aqui todo bien, el problema viene siendo que la cantidad de datos que se mostrara cada mes puede variar, aveces pueden ser 10 como otras veces 30 y la animación como tal no se ajusta al 100% el comportamiento de la etiqueta `<marquee>` ya que cuando son muchos datos la animación se corta e inicia desde 0, o cuando son muy pocos se hace muy larga para volver a iniciar, ¿Como hago para que detecte cuando llegue al final de toda la información?, como lo hace `<marquee>`.

No uso esta etiqueta ya que esta considerada como obsoleta.

```css
@keyframes marquee{

0%{top: 250px}
100%{top: -100em}

}

.animation{
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 7vh;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.user{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.picture{
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="animation">
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Los datos son traidos de una tabla de la base de datos, y los muestro mediante un `foreach`, por lo cual no puedo controlar cuantos usuarios se mostraran, y no puedo estar cambiando el codigo `css` todos los meses para que cuadre al 100% como lo necesito.

Se que el inconveniente esta en `100%{top: -100em}`, que es la distancia que le doy a la animación, pero como hago en el `-100em`, detecte el final de la información y comienze el ciclo de nuevo, justo igual que `<marquee>`.

**Esto es lo que busco exactamente**

```css
.animation{
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.user{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.picture{
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<marquee direction="up">
<div class="animation">
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
</marquee>
```

Pero no se como detectar el final de los datos para que inicie nuevamente la animación

Comment: Existen varias preguntas en el sitio con temas parecido a este y que te pueden servir de ayuda. Deberías buscar y ver si alguna de ellas te vale.

Comment: @alvaroMontoro hermano no encontre ninguna pregunta que me ayudara con el problema, por eso abri esta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He estado haciendo pruebas con el código que facilitas y me está dando bastantes buenos resultados usar **vh** en vez de los **em** que estás usando tú.

**CSS**

```
@keyframes marquee{

0%{top: 250px}
100%{top: -100vh}

}
```

Esta medida relativa hace referencia a la altura del dispositivo donde se esté visualizando.

**EDIT**

Lo primero, perdona por la tardanza en contestar, que te he dejado un poco colgado. Si aun te hace falta una solución, la que yo encontré en su día sería algo así:

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="animation">
<div id="users">
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>

  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>

  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>

  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <p class="text">
        <b> Jose Perez </b>
        <br>
        <span class="client">Movistar</span>
     </p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#users {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 250px;
}

.animation{
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 7vh;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.user{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.picture{
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var altura = $('#users').height();

marquee();

function marquee () {
    $("#users").animate({top: -altura}, 5000, function () {
        $('#users').css('top', '250px');
        marquee();
    });
}
```

Lo único que añadí al **HTML** fue un **div** que contenga a todos los que tengan la clase **user**, lo he llamado **users**. Esto lo hago porque este **div** me facilitará la altura de la suma de los **divs** con la clase **user**.

En el **CSS** le di estilos a este nuevo **div**, además de darle un **position: relative** a la clase **animation**. Esto lo hago para que el elemento **id="users"** ocupe el mismo espacio que su padre **animation**.

Y por el último el **Jquery**, aquí está la miga. Lo primero que hago es calcular la altura que mide el elemento **id="users"**, que mide lo que la suma de sus hijos, esta altura me servirá para saber lo que tengo que mover el elemento para que la animación funcione independientemente del número de elementos con la clase **user** que existan. Y después creo una función recursiva (que se llama a sí misma) y la lanzo cada vez que finalice la animación en curso, así no se pisan las animaciones. Antes de volver a llamarla reseteo su posición para que vuelva a estar debajo del elemento **animation** que es la posición de origen que se le dio para que pareciese que la animación aparece desde debajo.

Comment: por favor añade el código de tu respuesta aquí, a pesar de que pones el enlace si este deja de servir los demas usuarios que consulten se pierden de tu respuesta

Comment: hermano hize el cambio y realize una prueba para que mostrara unos 10 registros, pero igual no lo muestra todos, llega como a la mitad del octavo y se corta y vuelve a iniciar la animación, supongo porque pasaron los `15s` que le defini. Aun no me los muestra todos como necesito

Comment: @shadow Solo puse el enlace para que se viese una prueba ejecutable. El código de mi respuesta está añadido en la propia respuesta. Aun así investigaré como se hacen los snippes.

Comment: @EdwinAquino Para que fuese 100% fiable, se tendría que determinar la altura que ocupa la suma de los **div class="user"** y usarla para el desplazamiento hacia arriba. He hecho cosas parecidas con Jquery, pero ahora mismo no caigo en hacerlo con **CSS**. Tendría que investigar un poquejo para saber si se puede hacer.

Comment: Y como se haria con jquery?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta para darte una posible solución con Jquery. Al final no me fue posible encontrar una con CSS.

Comment: Excelente hermano, es justo lo que necesitaba, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí puedes observar un ejemplo usando keyframes para crear animaciones en CSS

```css
.marquee {
  height: 55px;
  width: 420px;

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;

  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;

  animation: marquee 2s linear infinite;
}

.marquee p {
  float: right;
  display:inline;
  height: 50px
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div>
    <p>
      Esta es mi animacion
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
```