# Imagen que recorre posición de izquierda a derecha de forma lenta en modo bucle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estoy intentando hacer que unas circunferencia con una imagen dentro, recorran de izquierda a derecha lentamente y se siga repitiendo, quiero meter varios y ocupar una buena parte, pero no se muy bien como hacerlo, estoy probando con `transform translate` pero sin mucho éxito.

HTML:

```
<img src="images/centros/youClinics.jpg"  class="imgCentro168">
```

Jquery:

```
$('.imgCentro168').animate({  left: 200, fake2: 10 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','translate('+now+'px,'+now+'px )');

    },
    duration:'slow'

    },'linear');
```

CSS:

```
.imgCentro168 {
    width: 89px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50,50,93,.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -258px;
    top: -150px;
    z-index: 1;
    will-change: transform,opacity;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres? ¿Qué parta de la izquierda, desaparezca por el borde derecho de la pantalla y reaparezca por la izquierda y así sucesivamente?

Comment: Hola @phpMyGuel si correcto, tendré mas de una figura que iran a la par, para que la pantalla nunca se quede vacia

Comment: Podrías hacer algo como esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203769/como-imitar-el-comportamiento-de-marquee-con-una-animaci%C3%B3n-css/203785#203785 Esta solución la di en su día para hacer lo que quieres en vertical, pero podría adaptarse fácilmente para funcionar horizontalmente.

Comment: Estoy mirado tu publicación @phpMyGuel haber si consigo comprenderla entera jajajaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo he usado una animación, si no sabes lo que es, o como usarlo, te dejo un enlace [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) a una página que lo explica muy bien.

También te dejo un ejemplo en vivo [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation_count) sobre este ejemplo en específico

La animación no se va a repetir indefinidamente, en caso de necesitar que se ejecute una cantidad específica, lo puedes configurar cambiando el valor de `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`.

```css
 .circulo{
  border: solid red 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 }
 
 @keyframes example {
  0%   {left:-15%; top:0px;}
  100%  {left:115%; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="circulo">
  img
</div>
<br>
<div class="circulo">
  img
</div>
```

Salu2

Comment: Hola #javiertxu18 pero necesitaria que al teminar en la derecha vuelva a aparecer en la izquierda pero sin retorno, imaginemos una marquesina que pasa una y otra vez, y más teniendo en cuenta que iran muchos más circulos

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, puedes poner todos los circulos que quieras añadiendo divs de clase circulo, te recomiendo visitar el enlace que he puesto, te va a venir muy bien para el futuro, ay que explican de todo

Comment: Más o menos esta cerca de lo que necesito, mira te pongo una web donde lo ponen en practica.  https://stripe.com/es-ES/customers

Comment: Los círculos hacen lo mismo que los de la página que me has mandado, solo tienes que crear más con diferentes tamaños y posiciones de inicio

Comment: Perfecto estoy usando esta solución, aunque me hubiese gustado más hacerlo con jquery

Answer (score 5):

Aunque ya has marcado una respuesta como válida, aquí te dejo la mía

Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/marquee

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right">
    <img src="http://clinicavillasanta.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/usuario.jpeg" width="100px" height="100px">
</marquee>
```

Comment: ¡Vaya! Desconocía la existencia de esa etiqueta. Muy interesante.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var anchura = $('#users').width();

marquee();

function marquee () {
    $("#users").animate({left: anchura}, 5000, function () {
        $('#users').css('left', '-100%');
        marquee();
    });
}
```

```css
#users {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
}

.animation{
  text-align: right;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 7vh;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.user{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.picture{
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="animation">
<div id="users">
  <div class="user">
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
     <i class="far fa-user-circle picture"></i>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esto sería más o menos el código que te pasé en el link adaptado a modo horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo puede servirte:

```css
.prueba {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {/*background-color:red;*/ left:0px; top:0px;}
    75%  {/*background-color:green;*/ left:100px; top:0px;}
    100% {/*background-color:red;*/ left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {/*background-color:red;*/ left:0px; top:0px;}
    75%  {/*background-color:green;*/ left:100px; top:0px;}
    100% {/*background-color:red;*/ left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
    <img class="prueba" id="cara1" src="https://actualizaweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/x3media-men1.png">
```

Comment: Hola gracia, puede llegar hasta el final y volver al principio sin hacer el retorno??